# Yitang Zhang: Prime Gaps

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

Has anybody read [Yitang Zhang](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2013/05/twin-primes/)'s paper on prime gaps? Wired reports "$70$ million" at most, but I was wondering if the number was actually more specific.

**EDIT**$^1$:

Are there any experts here who can explain the proof? Is the outline in the annals the preprint or the full accepted paper?

Comment: No doubt, Yitang Zhang's life will change as a result!

Comment: I love that he's from a little known place.

Comment: @Trancot, and over 50.

Comment: I find it really inspiring...kind of an "in your face, so there" thang!

Comment: You can download a copy of the full accepted paper on the [Annals page](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/articles/7954) if your institution subscribes to the Annals.

Comment: @lhf What database would that be available through? Ebsco? Jstor? AMS? MathSci?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that Annals allows early access. Indeed, I have done as lhf has mentioned and examined (briefly) the paper (which is not to say that I can now explain it). Thanks @lhf

Comment: I obtained a copy of the paper at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0z53pwkv6387t0/YitangZhang.pdf), for anyone of potential interest.

Comment: From Tao's G+ feed: https://plus.google.com/114134834346472219368/posts/39tuzQ8npYt. The current bound is 59,470,640.

Comment: Now it is 48,112,378. See http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/i-just-cant-resist-there-are-infinitely-many-pairs-of-primes-at-most-59470640-apart/ and the comments there.

Comment: I believe now it is $\leq$ 13,008,612!!!

Comment: And now, it is at most 4,802,222.

Comment: As spectator sports go, this is ridiculously engaging. The bound is now at most 388,248.

Comment: For an up-to-date table of "records", with references, see column 4 of the table at http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes#World_records

Comment: A paper is currently being written as a result of the Polymath project. The value they stopped at is 4,680. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/polymath8-writing-the-paper/

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Hah! Wow, that's a lot of progress fast...

Comment: GOOD FOR HIM! AND YET ANOTHER COUNTEREXAMPLE TO THE OLD "SCIENCE IS A GAME FOR THE YOUNG,OVER 30,YOU'RE FINISHED" MALARKY!

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: Turn your hearing aid up, grandpa... you're yelling again. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

70 million is exactly what is mentioned in the [abstract](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2014/179-3/p07).

It is quite likely that this bound can be reduced; the author says so in the paper:

> This result is, of course, not optimal. The condition $k_0 \ge 3.5 \times 10^6$ is also crude and there are certain ways to relax it. To replace the right side of (1.5) by a value as small as possible is an open problem that will not be discussed in this paper.

He seems to be holding his cards for the moment...

You can download a copy of the full accepted paper on the [Annals page](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2014/179-3/p07) if your institution subscribes to the Annals.

Comment: That is so odd. Well, I mean it's even, but it is strange.

Comment: For one, the paper does actually say that the result is not optimal. For two, the limit inferior must be even, as you are taking the difference of two odd numbers (consecutive primes). This result also does not say much about related conjectures: the Hardy-Littlewood k-tuple conjecture being probably the most important. It is my belief that a proof of the twin prime conjecture, done right, will also prove most, if not all, of the related conjectures.

Comment: The original bound has been drastically reduced. See the $H$ column in http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes#World_records.

Comment: Both links appear broken...

Comment: @barto, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As to the "idea" of the proof, I would suggest looking at the [following](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131185/philosophy-behind-yitang-zhangs-work-on-the-twin-primes-conjecture/131354#131354).

As mentioned by Mark Lewko, according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PrimePi%28n%29-+PrimePi%283500000%29++%3D+%283500000%29), the proof gives a gap size of $63, 374, 610.$

Comment: Please try to describe as much here as possible in order to make the answer self-contained. Links are fine as support, but they can go stale and then an answer which is nothing more than a link loses its value.

Answer (score 1):

It's now down to 600.

See here:
https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/polymath/

Comment: That post actually says it's down to 246.